# What van is this?

Tags: van

Is it a VW Type 2? I saw it on a TV show.

[image]

Comment: It  looks like a Soviet UAZ-452 (УАЗ-452) or variant

Comment: Its not a VW, insignia on the front is not the VW insignia

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The classic VW vans were rear engined, so no radiator grille at the front. The shape of the front bodywork and the position of the lights is also not a VW.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why not ask the vlogger?  He tells us in this video at the 18 second mark of the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxh80TEs79s

Answer (score 4):

Using a handful of internet tools such as Google image lookup, I found [this](https://www.picuki.com/media/2202358768098915430) Instagram post where one of the tags says "#uaz452". Comparing the picture in the Instagram post and the video of which you posted the thumbnail, you can tell by the licence plate that they are the same vehicle.

After comparing this picture with google images of a UAZ-452, I think I can safely conclude that what you are looking at here, is a UAZ-452.